# Share codes between Win7, Win8.1,Silverlight and windows phone 8.1

Tags: wpf, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, silverlight-5.0, windows-phone-8.1

I am a WPF developer and am planning to create an easily extendable application reusable in `Silverlight` , `Win7` , `Win8.1(Metro)` and `Windows phone 8.1` ,

I'm going to use [MahApps.Metro](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/) as UI and also use some benefits of `PRISM` and `ReactiveUI`.

How can I share most common codes between them?

Comment: Windows phone 8.1 comes in 2 variants, for Silverlight and universal apps. which one do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that you can share between those types of application is generic code (view models, business logic, data objects etc.) in a Portable Class Library, and you will be limited to the APIs available to the Portable Class Library.

You cannot really share any UI (XAML) code between Win 7 and Win 8 or WinPhone applications.

Answer (score 0):

There are two techniques to share code in such a scenario:

- Linked files / shared projects
- PCL (portable class libraries)

See http://www.kenneth-truyers.net/2013/03/27/portable-class-libraries-or-source-code-sharing/

Most probably, XAML code cannot be shared in your scenario because the XAML differs too much between Win7, SL and WinRT.